# Pasar iterador a una función en C++

Tags: c++

He creado un iterador, al momento de usarlo todo funciona bien; sin embargo, cuando intento pasarlo a una función y utilizarlo de la misma forma que antes me sale el error `Violación de segmento ('core' generado)`.

Mi código va así:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Token {
private:
    string valor;
public:
    Token();
    Token(string valor_): valor(valor_) {}
    string getValor(){ return valor; }
};

void eval_expresion(vector<Token>::iterator it, vector<Token> tokens){
    // cout << it->getValor() << endl;
    for(; it != tokens.end(); it++){
        cout << it->getValor() << " ";
    }
}

int main(){
    vector<Token> tokens;
    tokens.push_back(Token("var"));
    tokens.push_back(Token("="));
    tokens.push_back(Token("10"));

    vector<Token>::iterator it_tokens;

    for(it_tokens = tokens.begin(); it_tokens != tokens.end(); it_tokens++){
        Token tk = *it_tokens;
        if(tk.getValor() == "var") eval_expresion(it_tokens, tokens);
    }
}
```

Me resulta raro, pues si descomento la línea de `cout << it->getValor() << endl;`, pues esto me muestra el valor correctamente y según yo uso el iterador correctamente, lo uso igual que en el primer `for`.

Comment: Aquí tienes un video muy recomendable sobre iteradores: https://youtu.be/F9eDv-YIOQ0

Comment: Gracias, lo revisaré

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu problema es muy simple:

1. Creas un contenedor.

   ```
   vector<Token> tokens;
   ```
2. Creas un iterador **sobre el contenedor**.

   ```
   it_tokens = tokens.begin();
   ```
3. Pasas **una copia** del iterador a la función y
4. Pasas **una copia** del contenedor a la función.

   ```
   void eval_expresion(vector<Token>::iterator it, vector<Token> tokens) { ... }
   ...
   eval_expresion(it_tokens, tokens);
   ```

Pues ya está: el iterador se ha creado por un contenedor ... y tu pretendes usarlo **en un contenedor distinto** (una copia de algo **no es el mismo algo** que lo original):

```
for(; it != tokens.end(); it++){
```

La solución es tan sencilla como **pasar a la función el mismo contenedor** desde el que creas el iterador. Por ejemplo, por referencia:

```
void eval_expresion(vector<Token>::iterator it, vector<Token> &tokens){
```